# Can existing user group permissions be changed when I "stop inheriting permissions"?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions

I'm trying to keep people from overwriting files in a document library on SharePoint as well as saving files to the library itself.

I know this can be achieved by changing the permissions for this library, but if I stop inheriting permissions, can I still use the same groups I already have but give them different permissions? Or do I have to create new groups and add those people into it with the permissions I want?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will still be able to use the same groups -- in fact, it will make a copy of the permissions you have and then you can manually adjust their permissions from there.

Comment: Excellent, thanks Trevor! I just didn't want to mess things up without knowing what to expect.